# How to multiply the value of the array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
Array ([1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0.12403251859952)
Array ([1] => 0 [2] => 0.227645 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0.0310081)
```

How to get the result of the multiply of the array

Comment: what do you mean by multiplication of the array ? what do you want to multiply ?

Comment: use a foreach statement to iterate through each element of the array

Comment: Which values do you want to multiply with which ones?

Comment: i'm sorry 
yes multiply from values array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If your 2 arrays are of same size use foreach and mutiply each values.

```
$arr1=array (1 => 0, 2 => 0 ,3 => 0,4 => 0, 5 => 0.12403251859952);
$arr2=array (1 => 0, 2 => 0.227645, 3 => 0 ,4 => 0 ,5 => 0.0310081);
$mul= array();
foreach ($arr1 as $key=>$val) {
    $mul[] = $val * $arr2[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin element wise vector multiplication function in php as far as I know.

You could if you really want install http://www.ctolib.com/phpnum.html#mult and use the mult function.

Alternatively you could write a for loop which creates a new array that contains the product of the elements in each of the arrays at the index of the for loop.